# Django Filter returning empty set for a thread id,but , thread is present in db

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I Have this following line in views.py file

```
message_rows=HostedEvents.objects.filter(thread_id=decl_th.thread_mapping.original_id)
logger.debug('message rows are {}'.format(message_rows))
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

Output:
`message rows are []`

(pdb)

```
HostedEvents.objects.filter(thread_id=decl_th.thread_mapping.original_id)
[<<  HostedEvents: 15dcaea4b6657031 - 15dcaea4b6657031>>]
```

How come message rows are empty, where as in pdb which is immediate to that line, while calling from pdb, that code is working.

Moreover for suppose if there are thread with three message id's, this is happening for every first thread and remaining two are working properly.

One more thing if "X" is a thread id with three children , one of the children(first one)'s id is same as thread_id.

Comment: add to log the value of decl_th.thread_mapping.original_id

Comment: it's returning "15dcaea4b6657031"

Comment: i'm not sure but you can try `logger.debug('message rows are {}'.format(list(message_rows)))`

Comment: still empty list

Comment: Please post your models.